# How to solve this Wrong Data argument not used by format String?

Tags: ios, ios8

How to solve this wrong (Data argument not used by format string)?

This is my code:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSHomeDirectory(void);

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyDayJournal.plist",NSHomeDirectory()];
    NSFileManager *man=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if([man fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        [dataArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    }
    [dataArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    [tableView1 reloadData];
}
```

Wrong show on `NSHomeDirectory()`. Why does it show wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because method `stringWithFormat:` has one-to-one relationship between format specifiers and number of arguments being passed to it.
In your code you are writing `@"MyDayJournal.plist"` as the format string and then later on passing `NSHomeDirectory()` as an argument, but there is no format specifier to recieve this input. Something like `@"%@/MyDayJournal.plist"`. Your code should be like

```
NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MyDayJournal.plist",NSHomeDirectory()];
```